# Wrong dimensions when using \XeTeXpicfile with CMYK image

Tags: graphics, xetex

When including images in XeTeX using `\XeTeXpicfile` I noticed that the dimensions of the output picture are wrong. I created the following MWE:

```
\nopagenumbers
% The TeXbook, p. 311
\def\hidehrule#1#2{\kern-#1%
  \hrule height#1 depth#2 \kern-#2 }
\def\hidevrule#1#2{\kern-#1{\dimen0=#1
    \advance\dimen0 by#2\vrule width\dimen0}\kern-#2 }
\def\makeblankbox#1#2{\hbox{\lower\dp0\vbox{\hidehrule{#1}{#2}%
    \kern-#1 % overlap the rules at the corners
    \hbox to \wd0{\hidevrule{#1}{#2}%
      \raise\ht0\vbox to #1{}% set the vrule height
      \lower\dp0\vtop to #1{}% set the vrule depth
      \hfil\hidevrule{#2}{#1}}%
    \kern-#1\hidehrule{#2}{#1}}}}

\def\pic#1{\setbox0=\vbox{\XeTeXpicfile #1 width 8cm}
  \vbox{\leavevmode\copy0\kern-\wd0\makeblankbox{.25pt}{.25pt}}}

\pic{test-cmyk300.jpg}
\bigskip
\pic{test-cmyk72.jpg}
\bigskip
\pic{test-rgb300.jpg}
\bye
```

Please download [test-cmyk300.jpg](http://stackexchange.marcelkorpel.nl/test-cmyk300.jpg), [test-cmyk72.jpg](http://stackexchange.marcelkorpel.nl/test-cmyk72.jpg) and [test-rgb300.jpg](http://stackexchange.marcelkorpel.nl/test-rgb300.jpg) and watch the XeTeX output. (Side note: this is a detail of [The Haywain Triptych](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Haywain_Triptych).)

You'll notice that the 300 DPI CMYK image is enlarged, even though the parameter `width 8cm` is given. A workaround is to set the image resolution to 72 DPI, in which case the size is exactly right. Using a lower DPI setting the image is also scaled down. This problem doesn't exist with RGB images.

Is this a bug in XeTeX?

Comment: I suspect a bug in `xdvipdfmx` rather than XeTeX: I do see the erroneous behaviour here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further investigation, it turned out to be a bug in xdvipdfmx and is [fixed](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&revision=36287), thanks to Akira Kakuto.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in XeTeX and was fixed. See
http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2015-February/025727.html